# Define data type and use in function

Tags: haskell

How should I define tuple type `Quartet`, that will contain four elements – two `Integral`s and two `Boolean`s, and functions `firstTwo` returning table of Integrals and `secondTwo` returning table of two Booleans?

```hs
data Quartet = Quartet (Int, Int, Bool, Bool)

--firstPair :: Quartet -> [Int, Int]
firstPair (a, b, _) = [a, b]

--secondPair :: Quartet -> [Bool, Bool]
secondPair (_, _, a, b) = [a, b]
```

Answer (score 3):

As you have defined it, the `Quartet` value constructor takes one argument, which is a 4-tuple. You could also define it like this:

```
data Quartet = Quartet Int Int Bool Bool
```

and it will work pretty much the same except the pattern matching will be slightly different.

You can also make a type synonym for 4-tuples of this particular type:

```
type Quartet = (Int, Int, Bool, Bool)
```

If you opt for this final approach, your functions will work just as you've written them, because pattern matching in this last case is nothing more than matching against a plain tuple.

However, if you use either of the first two cases, the key idea is that in your function definition, you have to pattern match the value constructor, so you need to include the `Quartet` value constructor as part of the pattern:

```
--firstPair :: Quartet -> [Int, Int]
firstPair (Quartet (a, b, _, _)) = [a, b]

--secondPair :: Quartet -> [Bool, Bool]
secondPair (Quartet (_, _, a, b)) = [a, b]
```